# How to redirect all php requests to a different subdomain

Tags: redirect, apache2, subdomain

I have an application that I have rewritten with rails. Old application is in php.

I need to redirect all php requests to a subdomain old.example.com (I have put my old application to run there) so that the old links would still work. I believe all of the links have a ".php" in them and none of my new urls have that. So it could be used as a condition for redirecting.

I have planned to use apache RedirectMatch. So something like:

```
RedirectMatch \.php http://old.example.com
```

should be close. I believe. I just don't know how to pass the request path to the redirect rule.

Or if someone has a better idea how to do this?

Comment: I found out that there is a REQUEST_URI variable in Apache2. So I need to add that to the redirect url. What might be the syntax for doing that?

Comment: I tried `RedirectMatch permanent ^.*\.php.*$ http://old.example.com%{REQUEST_URI}` but didn't get that working. So I took the rewrite engine into use as suggested by Alex W.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Apache mod rewrite, you would use the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^.*\.php.*$ http://old.example.com/index.php [R=301,NC]
```

If you want to actually insert the page they were trying to reach in the redirect URL:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)\.php.*$ http://old.example.com/$1.php [R=301,NC]
```

`$1` will insert anything that matches the regular expression in the parentheses.

For GET parameters:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)\.php(.*)$ http://old.example.com/$1.php$2 [R=301,NC]
```

Comment: How about if there is some GET parameters in the url as well? I think they would not be included in those solutions. But could be included with a second (.*) after the .php ?

Comment: @Mika updated it for GET parameters.  You are correct, they could be included with a second pair of parentheses.

Comment: in http://www.webmasterworld.com/forum92/4307.htm I read that the `RewriteBase` should only be defined in .htaccess files. I'm going to put this inside `<VirtualHost>` tags in the server configuration file. Should I exclude the `RewriteBase` ?

Comment: @Mika It's fine to exclude that directive.